# rails 1 to 4 upgrading the :include keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a whole bunch of Rails 1 code that uses this syntax in models:

```
...
has_many :widgets, :class_name => 'WidgetAssertion', 
                   :include => [ :activity, :priority_assertion_type ]
...
```

Rails 4 throws an exception:

```
(ArgumentError in WhateverController#index) 
(Unknown key: :include. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key,
:validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, 
:after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, 
:source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type)
```

How can I port this to Rails 4?

Comment: You didn't have any "Rails 1" code that used that syntax that had any hope of working. Can you provide accurate information please? The stabby lambda was introduced in Ruby 1.9; if you have Rails 1 code running on Ruby 1.9 you likely have larger issues in play.

Comment: i edited it to reflect the actual code.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: edited question to show exception.

Comment: The exception you show is thrown in a controller. However the code you shown is part of a model. Please edit your question and show your *actual* code and the *actual* exception.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd argument of [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) is `scope`:

> You can pass a second argument `scope` as a callable (i.e. proc or lambda) to retrieve a specific set of records or customize the generated query when you access the associated collection.

So, in your example, you could do this:

```
has_many :widgets, -> { includes(:activity, :priority_assertion_type) },
         class_name: 'WidgetAssertion'
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!